# как бороться с ошибкой module 'pandas._libs.lib' has no attribute 'is_float'?

Tags: python, pandas

AttributeError: module 'pandas._libs.lib' has no attribute 'is_float'

```
D:\TensorFlowSamples\stock-rnn-master\scripts\train_model.py in <module>()
      6 import os
      7 import sys; sys.path.append("..")
----> 8 import tensorflow as tf
      9 
     10 from build_graph import build_lstm_graph_with_config

D:\Python_3.6.2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py in <module>()
     22 
     23 # pylint: disable=wildcard-import
---> 24 from tensorflow.python import *
     25 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import
     26 

D:\Python_3.6.2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py in <module>()
     80 from tensorflow.python import data
     81 from tensorflow.python import keras
---> 82 from tensorflow.python.estimator import estimator_lib as estimator
     83 from tensorflow.python.feature_column import feature_column_lib as feature_column
     84 from tensorflow.python.layers import layers

D:\Python_3.6.2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator_lib.py in <module>()
     35 from tensorflow.python.estimator.exporter import FinalExporter
     36 from tensorflow.python.estimator.exporter import LatestExporter
---> 37 from tensorflow.python.estimator.inputs import inputs
     38 from tensorflow.python.estimator.model_fn import EstimatorSpec
     39 from tensorflow.python.estimator.model_fn import ModeKeys

D:\Python_3.6.2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\inputs\inputs.py in <module>()
     20 
     21 # pylint: disable=unused-import,line-too-long
---> 22 from tensorflow.python.estimator.inputs.numpy_io import numpy_input_fn
     23 from tensorflow.python.estimator.inputs.pandas_io import pandas_input_fn
     24 

D:\Python_3.6.2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\inputs\numpy_io.py in <module>()
     21 import collections
     22 from six import string_types
---> 23 from tensorflow.python.estimator.inputs.queues import feeding_functions
     24 
     25 # Key name to pack the target into dict of `features`. See

D:\Python_3.6.2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\inputs\queues\feeding_functions.py in <module>()
     38 try:
     39   # pylint: disable=g-import-not-at-top
---> 40   import pandas as pd
     41   HAS_PANDAS = True
     42 except IOError:

D:\Python_3.6.2\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py in <module>()
     38 
     39 # let init-time option registration happen
---> 40 import pandas.core.config_init
     41 
     42 from pandas.core.api import *

D:\Python_3.6.2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\config_init.py in <module>()
     10 
     11 """
---> 12 import pandas.core.config as cf
     13 from pandas.core.config import (is_int, is_bool, is_text, is_instance_factory,
     14                                 is_one_of_factory, get_default_val,

D:\Python_3.6.2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\config.py in <module>()
    818 is_str = is_type_factory(str)
    819 is_unicode = is_type_factory(compat.text_type)
--> 820 is_text = is_instance_factory((str, bytes))
    821 
    822 

D:\Python_3.6.2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\config.py in is_instance_factory(_type)
    779     if isinstance(_type, (tuple, list)):
    780         _type = tuple(_type)
--> 781         from pandas.io.formats.printing import pprint_thing
    782         type_repr = "|".join(map(pprint_thing, _type))
    783     else:

D:\Python_3.6.2\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\printing.py in <module>()
      4 
      5 import sys
----> 6 from pandas.core.dtypes.inference import is_sequence
      7 from pandas import compat
      8 from pandas.compat import u

D:\Python_3.6.2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\inference.py in <module>()
     14 is_integer = lib.is_integer
     15 
---> 16 is_float = lib.is_float
     17 
     18 is_complex = lib.is_complex

AttributeError: module 'pandas._libs.lib' has no attribute
```

Comment: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7060/255866)

Comment: Похоже у вас как-то не так утсановлен модуль Pandas. Попробуйте установить Python, Tensorflow, Pandas (и остальные необходимые вам модули) из дистрибутива  Anaconda